# Adding new user to AWS EC2 - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, public-key

I am trying to set up a new user for my AWS EC2. I have followed step by step [this tutorial](http://www.ampedupdesigns.com/blog/show?bid=44) but I get `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

I tried as well creating a `newuser-key-pair.pem` from AWS EC2 console and `ssh -i newuser-key-pair.pem new-user@my-public-ip` but it didn't work.

I think the problem is that I generated a key pair (private key) but the public key that I uploaded to the AWS .ssh/authorized_keys is not linked to it. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can login to EC2 instance with the same access key you use for default user. Suppose, you are running Ubuntu and default username is `ubuntu`. Then your public key is located in `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Create new user as described in [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) and add public key to its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Now you should be able to login to you instance with original key pair.

Comment: It is not recommended to share a single ssh private key between multiple users. This makes security more difficult and forces you to give sudo permissions to all your users. Cracking a private key's pass phrase should take only a few hours if one of your users is compromised

Answer (score 1):

First Follow this to create and grant ssh permissions to new user.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Your public key can be found under: `/root/ssh/authorized_keys`. Remember to also change ownership of the folder `.ssh` and the file `authorized_keys`. Change the ownership to the newly created user:

```
sudo chown newuser:newuser -R path to new user folder/.ssh
```

Replace newuser with whatever you called your new user